# set first_name and second_name in python shell - django

Tags: python, django, shell

I changed the register logic where now new users have to give their first and second names also. But old users in db don't have those fields filled up, they are empty.

I am wondering now how to set them manually with `python manage.py shell`, I am using sqlite3, so there is no UI for the db.

is there any solution for it?

the one which came to my mind is to write a update-page for users where they can update their personal info. but then I would need to tell every one of them to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't know what you mean by "there is no UI for the db" - sqlite has a shell just like any other database, you can go in and write direct SQL update statements.

Secondly, setting fields in the Django shell is just the same as in a view: you import your models, query the instances you want, update the fields, and save the model.

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
my_instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=whatever)
my_instance.first_name = 'foo'
my_instance.last_name = 'bar'
my_instance.save()
```

Comment: oh my bad. of course, what a dumb question was that! thanks man

Answer (score 1):

If you are using south, you can do a [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations) which is like a schema migration, but deals with data.

You would create a migration, and then add the appropriate code to the `forwards` method. This way when this migration is applied, data is added for those users that do not have a first and last name.

The other option you have is to do this manually, from the django shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> model = get_user_model()
>>> no_names = model.objects.filter(first_name='', last_name='')
>>> no_names.update(first_name='First Name', last_name='Last Name')
```